# ssrs keep certain "chunks" of text "atomic" within a report header

Tags: reporting-services

I have some text I want to keep "atomic" within a report header. The text in question is the "Period Ending Date: 1/15/1998". It is OK if that block of text wraps down below, but I would like to keep the whole block of text together on one line. This has to be dynamic however, as the text will grow and shrink dynamically--sometimes the server and database and company name will be short and everything fits on one row, sometimes long even the database name will need to wrap.

[image]

And this is how I have it defined in the expression

[image]

Is keeping it "atomic" possible?

Comment: can you please paste the design of the SSRS report?

Comment: If you are that much curious about designs then why are you using the single text box and trying to display all as a single string? You should split the expression and put values in different text boxes so that your required design formatting can stay intact.

Comment: @CuriousKid The XML?

Comment: What do you mean by this? "It is OK if that block of text wraps down below, but I would like to keep the whole block of text together on one line"

Comment: It is OK if  "Period Ending Date: 1/15/1998" goes to the second line, but I would like that whole block of text to go down to the second line and not get split up.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say you basically have two options, either make the text box wide enough to fit any possible combination of company, server, database and end date that could occur - you can use max(len([your fields])) in SQL to determine the maximum possible characters and then figure out the width from your font information - or you can put the separate chunks of information into separate text boxes and arrange them however is most aesthetically pleasing to you. Personally I'd have a company name box on one line, the Server and database beneath it and the end date beneath that. Up to your preference though obviously.

Comment: Eh, I'm an independent contractor, so it's more about business requirements :) Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff.Clark, I guess you need to rethink the design. I agree with @Viking's comment. As far as i know, what you are trying to achieve is not possible in SSRS (keeping the Can Grow = False) and want to wrap it on the field level not the word level. I tried using it in the placeholder but it is splitting the field.

However, if your requirements are very critical and no matter what you have to do it in this way then i think you can achieve it by determining maximum characters the cell can accommodate in one line and then subtracting the SUM of LENGTH of the the fields+ the text(ex: "Totals per payroll period") and find out a position in your string to insert `VBCRLF` so the rest of the data will go to next line. Without the original expression i will not be able to provide the accurate updated expression but it will be nested IIFs to get the position of `VBCRLF`. I personally do not prefer this method because it will take lot of processing on the report design level and can affect the overall performance of the report as well as not very pretty when it comes to the maintenance of the report.